# Regressing adjusted-R2 on a constant

Tags: confidence-interval, r-squared, robust-standard-error

Lets say I have a panel of adjusted-R2 statistics from some regressions involving experiment / survey data. Can I regress these adjusted-R2 statistics on a constant to find the average adjusted-R2, and the 95% confidence interval associated with the average R2?

In particular, I have data on multiple individuals and conduct an experiment on each individual three times a day (morning, afternoon, and evening). I then regress the outcome of the experiment for each individual on a number of covariates and, among other things, record the adjusted-R2. I now want to find the average adjusted-R2 across all my regressions and have some kind of confidence interval around it.

Can I run the the simple regression outlined above to do this? Ideally, I would like my confidence interval to be constructed using robust standard errors.

**Edit:** To make the question more general, if I have data for two countries and run the following regression *within each country* (note, the $i$ here indexes country):

$Y_{i}=X_{i}\beta + \varepsilon_{i}$

And $X_{i}$ represent the same variables within each country / individuals / firms, can i interpret the average $\bar{R}^{2}$ from the two regressions as the average variation in $Y$ that $X$ explains across the countries / individuals / firms?

Comment: What is the interpretation and value of this average adjusted $R^2$?

Comment: The question that must be answered is this:  ¿Is the average of the coefficients of determination a meaningful number? Stated another way, once you have this "average", how is it supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: Leaving the particulars of the experiment aside, I want a sense of (on average) how much variation in the outcome variable the covariates explain.

Comment: When you "average across all regressions", does that mean you are averaging across regression models corresponding to different individuals? If yes, it's not clear to me why you are not considering a mixed effects model instead of separate models for each of your individuals. Or maybe I don't understand your setup?

Comment: Yes, in this particular analysis I am averaging across regression models corresponding to different individuals.

My main analysis involves a number of different specifications (including mixed effects) but a discussant at a conference urged me to estimate a very basic OLS setup and look at the average adjusted-R2 across models.

Comment: To put the same question a different way (and avoid issues related to my setup), if I had a model with k covariates attempting to forecast unemployment in n countries, and i obtained an adjusted-R2 for my model in each country, could i average these R2's across countries?